# How to find minimum dimensionality given sets of pairwise distances

Tags: general-topology

Suppose I have a set of pairwise distances in some Euclidean space of unknown dimensionality in which I have measured each distance from Point A to another point (B, C, D, E).  In data from another experiment, I have a second set of pairwise distances from point B to the remaining points (A, C, D, E).  For technical reasons, I cannot combine the two experiments.  (I have not, but in principle could, repeat the experiment over and acquire all distances from C, all distances from D, and all distances from E).

These two sets of distances are not compatible with one another in a two-dimensional Euclidean space; that is, they cannot both be mapped into the same space such that all measured distances are true.

Presumably there is a higher-dimensional space in which all of my measured pairwise distances can be simultaneously true.

How do I find the minimum dimensionality of such a space for a given set of data points?

Thanks for any guidance you may be able to offer.

Thom

Answer (score 1):

If the distance measurements are compatible with *any* metric space, they can also be realized in the Euklidean plane:
Pick $A$ arbitrary, $B$ at the correct distance $AB$. Then $C$ must be one of th etwo intersection points of the circle of radius $AC$ around $A$ and the circle of radius $BC$ around $B$. If these circles do *not* intersect, the distances violate the triangle inequality and hence the distances are not compatible with *any* metric space!
Likewise, you can find (typically two) inersection points for $D$ and $E$.